# Increasing the impression of depth when using fake bump displacement?

Tags: displacement, bump

I wanted to use a pure black and white logo image, i.e. no grayscale, to create an engraved effect on a surface using fake bump (i.e. *Displacement* set to *Bump Only*) and was disappointed with the result I achieved.

So what does one need to do to maximize the impression of depth when using fake bump?

I tried experimenting myself and found that the more I blurred my image, i.e. introduced more grays at the transition (the edges) between my logo and its background, the greater the impression of depth. As seen in this image (rendered with Cycles):

[image: cycles render]

The image on the left is my original b&w logo. Then to the right of it, logos where a Gaussian blur was applied of size 0.75, 1.5, 3.0 and 6.0 respectively using *Gimp*.

As you can see there's almost no impression of depth when using the original unblurred logo. What can I do to increase the impression of depth? Is blurring things really the way to go?

Just for reference, the impression of depth is greater when rendered with Eevee:

[image: eevee render]

This is the node setup that I'm using for my materials:

[image: nodes]

In my real project, I'm using UV unwrapping and a few more nodes but for these experiments, I just kept things simple.

Here's my `.blend` file (created with Blender 3.1.2), packed with the original logo and the blurred versions:

[image]

Comment: blurring is a way to increase the impression of depth, but anyway it will always be limited